# Can Demigods use non-cellphone Modern Tech?

Tags: percy-jackson

In the Percy Jackson universe Demigods are unable to use phones as they attract monsters but are they able to use other modern tech like PDAs, Laptops, GPSes, etc...? Are there any in-universe example?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. For example, there's Daedalus's laptop, in turn inherited by Annabeth.

There are also all sorts of fancypants technology that isn't muggle in a sequel series, from the bronze dragon to Argo II and its flying table, to magical astrolabe, to Archimedes spheres; but I'm not sure if these fit the question's scope.

Answer (score 2):

## Things that are safe to use

- Deadalus's laptop (Note: This is different than a regular laptop)
- Tape players
- Magical dragons
- Other magical technologies

## Things that are not safe to use

- Cell phones
- Laptops<sup>1</sup>

## Things  that we don't know

- Payphone<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>In *The Lost Hero*, Piper McLean has a video call with her father - in a room *plated with celestial bronze*. Also, before she went in, Chiron tells her about a young man who</sub>

> <sub>Googled the Gorgons and got a bit more than he expected</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>In *The Son of Neptune*, Percy Jackson uses a payphone. A few minutes later, they're attacked by gryphons, but I'm not sure if they were related.</sub>

Comment: Technically, it was the Internet that did it.  Using a laptop is safe, unless you go online.